# Copying range of cells generates object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy paste from an assigned variable worksheet to another.

I've been able to make do by recording but I would like to know how to do it manually.

This is the code I made:

```
Sub Parse_Reportable()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Sheets.Add.Name = "Copy to Reportable or TAK"

Set ws = Sheets("Copy to Reportable or TAK")

Sheets("sheet1").Select

Range("H3", Cells.Columns(8).End(x1Down)).Copy

ws.Cells(2, 2).Paste

End Sub
```

Running it creates the worksheet but gives me an

```
object defined error
```

in the copy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells.Columns(8).End(x1Down)` will give you the error. It also has a typo. `x1Down`

Instead of using `xlDown`, use `xlUp` to find the last row using [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) and then construct your range to copy.

Is this what you are trying?  (**Untested**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Parse_Reportable()
    Dim rngToCopy
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Sheets.Add.Name = "Copy to Reportable or TAK"

    Set ws = Sheets("Copy to Reportable or TAK")

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        lRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngToCopy = .Range("H3:H" & lRow)
    End With

    rngToCopy.Copy ws.Cells(2, 2)
End Sub
```

**Note**: You may also want to delete the sheet "*Copy to Reportable or TAK*" if it already exists before naming the new sheet with that name else you will again get an error.

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Copy to Reportable or TAK").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

Sheets.Add.Name = "Copy to Reportable or TAK"
```